# How to get custom exit code from makefile in external application

Tags: bash, makefile, subprocess

suppose, we got following Makefile:

```
test:
    exit 123
```

if we run test target in console we got:

```
$ make test
exit 123
make: *** [Makefile:2: test] Error 65
```

trying to run it in bash script and get exit code:

bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
f()
{
  (make test)
  local excode=$?
  echo "!! $excode"
}

f
```

running in console:

```
$ ./test.sh
exit 123
make: *** [Makefile:2: test] Error 65
!! 2
```

python script:

```
import os
import subprocess as sp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    child = sp.Popen(["make", "test"], stdout=sp.PIPE)
    streamdata = child.communicate()[0]
    print(streamdata, child.returncode)
```

run python:

```
$ python t.py
make: *** [Makefile:2: test] Error 65
b'exit 123\n' 2
```

So we got exit code 2, not 123.
Is there any common way to detect custom exit code, avoiding additional parsing?

Comment: The exit code of a process in POSIX standard is 8 bits long, so the maximum exit code in POSIX is 127.  Also values 126 and 127 are by convention reserved for the shell to return errors to the caller, like if the program was not found.  So you should limit your programs to exiting with values between 0 and 125.

Comment: Makefile will always return 0,1 or 2 as exit code (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Running.html) you will probably need to change your approach if you want to get the exit code from outside the Makefile. You could display it and parse it, put it in an env variable and get it after ...